# C# - Remove a item from list of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, list

How can I remove a item from list of KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have both the key and the value you can do the following

```
public static void Remove<TKey,TValue>(
  this List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> list,
  TKey key,
  TValue value) {
  return list.Remove(new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(key,value)); 
}
```

This works because `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` does not override Equality but is a struct.  This means it uses the default value equality.  This simply compares the values of the fields to test for equality.  So you simply need to create a new `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` instance with the same fields.

**EDIT**

To respond to a commenter, what value does an extension method provide here?

Justification is best seen in code.

```
list.Remove(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(key,value));
list.Remove(key,value);
```

Also in the case where either the key or value type is an anonymous type, an extension method is required.

**EDIT2**

Here's a sample on how to get KeyValuePair where one of the 2 has an anonymous type.

```
var map = 
  Enumerable.Range(1,10).
  Select(x => new { Id = x, Value = x.ToString() }).
  ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

The variable map is a `Dicitonary<TKey,TValue>` where `TValue` is an anonymous type.  Enumerating the map will produce a KeyValuePair with the `TValue` being the same anonymous type.

Comment: Aside from the few syntax errors contained, what value is this extension method intending to provide?

Comment: @Derek, removes the need to specify any generic arguments to a type definition when doing a remove.  list.Remove(key,value) vs. list.Remove(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(key,value)).  The former is much more concise.  Don't think a -1 is worthy of a minor syntax error

Comment: I voted this answer down because I didn't feel the use of an extension method provided a clear, concise answer or added value, not due to the syntax errors.

Comment: In response to the edited section, the provision of a slightly more convenient API is an obvious benefit in need of no such example.  While more convenient, I would argue that the method signature of List.Remove(string, string) isn't particularly intention revealing.  I would also question whether proper encapsulation was being performed if values were being removed in the number of places to make such a convenience worth while.  [continued]

Comment: That said, I'm curious about the second reason you provided which was to accommodate anonymous types.  Can you provide an example of how a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> would be declared with an anonymous type for either the key or value?  I've never had such a need or seen this technique used, but if possible I can definitely see a benefit in providing such an abstraction.

Comment: In response to edit 2, technically that's a projection not a declaration.  Nevertheless, this does demonstrate one way of solving the problem.  As a nod to creativity, I'm removing my down vote.  However, there is a simpler approach to this issue which I'll provide in an edit to my answer. I still question the usefulness of this approach though, due to the contention between the need for its frequent use to be beneficial and that its frequent use points to a code smell (i.e. why are items being removed from so many different places requiring an extension method to reduce the amount of coding?)

Answer (score 10):

Here are a few examples of removing an item from a list of KeyValuePair:

```
// Remove the first occurrence where you have key and value
items.Remove(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 0));

// Remove the first occurrence where you have only the key
items.Remove(items.First(item => item.Key.Equals(0)));

// Remove all occurrences where you have the key
items.RemoveAll(item => item.Key.Equals(0));
```

**EDIT**

```
// Remove the first occurrence where you have the item
items.Remove(items[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove all items in the list by key:

```
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.Key.Equals(keyToRemove));
```

Comment: Despite not being the best explained answer, this will in most cases actually do the trick when you have the value of the key to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to use the .Remove(), .RemoveAt(), or one of the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = list[i];
    list.Remove(kvp);
```

or

```
    list.Remove(list[1]);
```

You must obtain a reference to the object you want to remove - that's why I found the item I'm looking for and assigned to a KeyValuePair - since you're telling it to remove a specific item.

A better solution might be to use a dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (d.ContainsKey("somekey")) d.Remove("somekey");
```

This allows you to remove by the key value instead of having to deal with the list not being indexed by the key.

**Edit** you may not have to get a KeyValuePair reference first. Still, a dictionary is probably a better way to go.